# Comparação com banco de dados Postgresql utilizando C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Criei uma aplicação de Login, fiz a conexão com o banco de dados, consigo obter o usuário e senha cadastrado no meu banco. Porém o que eu quero, é, se o usuário tentar mais de três vezes entrar e tiver algo errado, bloquear os *textbox* e *button*.

Teria que fazer a comparação com o usuário cadastrado no banco.

Segue o código até onde eu fiz.

```
    {
        bool blnFound = false;
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=****;Database=HHH");
        conn.Open(); //abrir conexão
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from login where nome = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' and senha = '" + txtSenha.Text + "'",conn);
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(dr.Read())
        {
            blnFound = true;
            Principal pc = new Principal();
            pc.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        if(blnFound==false)
            MessageBox.Show("Nome ou senha estão incorrentos!","Erro",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Quando o usuário, errar sua senha ou seu usuario, os *textbox* ficaria desabilitado.
Mais ou menos assim: *txtUserName.Text.Enabled = false*

Comment: Tem claro, basta você editar a pergunta, postar tudo o que já fez e dizer onde você está enroscado. Talvez tenha um jeito até melhor do que está fazendo mas precisamos de mais detalhes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma variável no código, caso não queira adicionar uma coluna no banco para verificar quantas vezes foi tentado o login.

```
int tentativas = 0;

{
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=****;Database=HHH");
    conn.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from login where nome = '" + txtUserName.Text + "' and senha = '" + txtSenha.Text + "'",conn);
    NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(dr.Read())
    {
        Principal pc = new Principal();
        pc.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nome ou senha estão incorretos!", "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        tentativas++;
    }

    if (tentativas > 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login bloqueado")
        button1.Enabled = False;
    }   

    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Procure fazer uma função para esta rotina. 
Crie um laço para testar o usuário e a senha na quantidade de vezes que deseja (ou definiu para o sistema), assim você conseguirá fazer a validação, caso a validação ultrapasse a quantidade definida, pode travar o sistema, apresentar uma tela do sistema com erro, ou uma mensagem, e etc.